# Mod_rewrite in php not setting up request values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am currently struggling to create api points with php. I followed http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ tutorial where everything is working fine for me except for modrewrite part. I am using it like the following in my `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

With this rule, if there is no file or directory called `api/v1` then take the rest of the part and rewrite it to `api.php`.

So, if I have `localhost/api/v1/example?apiKey=w36fOc4vu6` then I should be getting `$_REQUEST['request'] == 'example'` and the `$_GET` as normal.

When I echo it in the `api.php`, I get the `$_GET` values but not the `$_REQUEST['request']` (which is nil). Am I missing something in the configuration?

I have checked that the mod_rewrite in enabled. Googled alot and couldn't find any explanation as to why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated for a php noob. :)

**EDIT1:** added link to the tutorial I was following.

**Edit2:** used `RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]`only in the .htaccess and `print_r()` get and request both. 
For `$_REQUEST`

```
Array ( [apiKey] => w36fOc4vu6 )
```

For `$_GET`, getting

```
Array ( [apiKey] => w36fOc4vu6 )
```

But I am still missing `example`from the key/values (the actual problem).

**Edit3:** `$_SERVER` has

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /api/v1/example?apiKey=w36fOc4vu6
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /api.php
[PATH_INFO] => /v1/example
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/v1/example
```

**Update:** Both of @mario and @Eiad were right. The problem was Multiviews was on. In the process of turning it off, I found out that I had `AllowOverride none` in the default config. So, my .htaccess wasn't even being read at all. Thank you very much. The problem is solved.

Comment: Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapping and the `RewriteCond`s unless that directory actually exists.

Comment: I tried that. But that doesn't help either. I am still getting nil for $_REQUEST.

Comment: Edit whatever alternatives you tried into the question. And `print_r` both $_GET and $_REQUEST (they ought to contain the same variables for recent setups.)

Comment: @mario I have done the edit. They contain exactly the same thing. but isn't that rule supposed to write `/api/v1/example?key=value` to `api.php?request=example?key=value` ?

Comment: That's what it ought to do. Print out `$_SERVER` to see if it was picked up as PATH_INFO, and disable MultiViews then. If it's not honoring the preset param or QSA flag, you'll have to delve into enabling the RewriteLog (or logging flag on Apache 2.4).

Comment: okay. I tried echoing $_SERVER. Here is what I found. 
`[REQUEST_URI] => /api/v1/example?apiKey=w36fOc4vu6` 
`[SCRIPT_NAME] => /api.php `
`[PATH_INFO] => /v1/example ` 
`[PATH_TRANSLATED] => /var/www/v1/example`

This is kind of wierd because the `PATH_INFO` is `v1/example`. and `PATH_TRANSLATED` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

and update

```
RewriteRule ^api/v1/(.*?)$ /api.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&request=$1 [L,NC,NS]
```

Comment: Thanx Eiad. But it didn't work. I still don't get `example` anywhere.

Comment: That's weird, since it is suppose to work fine even with your code.
And it's not a Multiviews issue